# When using ffmpeg, getting "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file." errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an `m3u8` file consisting of `.ts` files like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD

#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY

#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY

#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:3.856
http://v.link.to.file.com/6774.ts
#EXTINF:3.854
http://v.link.to.file.com/6775.ts
#EXTINF:3.853
http://v.link.to.file.com/6776.ts
#EXTINF:3.853
....
```

I use `ffmpeg` with:

```
ffmpeg -i https://link.to.file/clip/21/335.m3u8 -c copy pd.mkv
```

However, upon running I get a large number of warning messages with

```
[http @ 0x614ab40] Opening 'http://v.link.to.file.com/6774.ts' for reading
[matroska @ 0x6196fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2691798, current: 96743; changing to 2691798. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 0x6196fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2691859, current: 96846; changing to 2691859. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 0x6196fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2691859, current: 96869; changing to 2691859. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[matroska @ 0x6196fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2691798, current: 96775; changing to 2691798. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
....
```

Is there something wrong I am doing? What is the correct set of commands for the best quality stream? Thanks.